# XQuery counters inside a for

Tags: xml, xquery, counter

Let's say I have the XQuery code below:

```
   for $y in doc("file.xml")/A/B

        for $x in $y/C where $x/constraint1 != "-" and $x/constraint2 > 2.00
            do stuff
```

Can I use a counter, to count how many my code will enter inside the second for loop?
I tried this:

```
   for $y in doc("file.xml")/A/B
       let $i := 0
        for $x in $y/C where $x/constraint1 != "-" and $x/constraint2 > 2.00
            $i := $i + 1
```

but I got compile errors. I also I need to sum some constraints like this:

```
   for $y in doc("file.xml")/A/B
       let $i := 0
       let $sum := 0
        for $x in $y/C where $x/constraint1 != "-" and $x/constraint2 > 2.13
            $i := $i + 1
            $sum := $sum + $x/constraint2
```

but of course this didn't work either :(.

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.
Also, can you suggest a good book/tutorial/site for doing such stuff?

Answer (score 22):

You don't need it very often, but if you really do need a counter variable inside an XQuery `for` expression (analogous to `position()` in an `xsl:for-each`) you can use an `at` variable

```
for $x at $pos in //item return
  <item position="{$pos}" value="{string($x)}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have understood the basics of declarative paradigm.

Total count and sum would be:

```
let $items := doc('file.xml')/A/B/C[constraint1 != '-' and constraint2 > 2.13]
return ('Count:', count($items), 'Sum:', sum($items/constraint2))
```

Partial count and sum would be:

```
let $items := doc('file.xml')/A/B/C[constraint1 != '-' and constraint2 > 2.13]
for $pos in (1 to count($items))
return ('Count:', $pos, 'Sum:', sum($items[position() le $pos]/constraint2))
```

Answer (score 0):

To Display counter in loop the best and easier way is to add **at $pos** in your for loop. $pos will work as a counter.

Code Snippet :

```
{for $artist **at $pos** in (/ns:Entertainment/ns:Artists/ns:Name)

  return
      <tr><td>{$pos}&nbsp;&nbsp;
    {$artist}</td></tr>

}
```

**Output:**

```
1   Artist

2   Artist 

3   Artist 

4   Artist

5   Artist

6   Artist
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution, if you don't want to count or act on every item of a collection, but you want to count/act only, if a certain condition applies.
In that case you might remember the functional programming paradigm of XQuery and implement this counting/acting by using recursive function calls:

```
declare function ActIf($collection as element(*)*, $index as xs:integer, $indexMax as xs:integer, $condition as xs:string, $count as xs:integer) as xs:integer
{
if($index <= $indexMax) then
    let $element := $collection[$index]
    if($element/xyz/text() eq $condition) then
        (: here you can call a user-defined function before continuing to the next element :)
        ActIf($collection, $index + 1, $indexMax, $condition, $count + 1)
    else
        ActIf($collection, $index + 1, $indexMax, $condition, $count)
else (: no more items left:)
    $count
};
```

The more easier way would be the usage of an appropriate XPath expression:

```
for $element at $count in $collection[xyz = $condition]
return
    (: call your user-defined function :)
```

or even

```
myFunction($collection[xyz = $condition])
```

The recursive solution might be quite helpful, if you want to implement something more complex with XQuery...