# AsterixDB: Sparse Vector Product

Tags: database, sparse-matrix

I am attempting to do make a sparse vector product in AsterixDB, but I am confused about the syntax.

I can create a sparse vector type, but how would I create a function that would do implement the following pseudo-code?

```
use dataverse linalg
create type sparsevec as closed {
    ind: [int64],
    val: [double]
}

create type densevec as closed {
    val: [double]
}

create function prod(densevec v, sparsevec sv) {
    return sum( for i in range(len($sv.ind))
                return $v.val[$sv.ind[i]] * $sv.val[i] )
}
```

There is an obvious Python influence in my code, but I think this should make sense.

Comment: sum(for $x in [1, 2, 3] return $x); works

Comment: In the AsterixDB publication "AsterixDB: A Scalable, Open Source BDMS", it is stated that the query language is based on XQuery!!! so I tried, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652397/xquery-counters-inside-a-for and the solution "for $x at $i in [1, 3, 4] return [$i, $x];" worked!!

Comment: Almost!! let $X := [1, 4, 7]
select sum(for $v at $i in $X return $v*$X[$i-1]);